# Open a link that is inside a iframe with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have `IFrame` in my page and a link inside it, i want to open that link immediately after opening my page.
for example i have a page `index.html` and inside this page i have an `IFrame` and inside this `IFrame` i have a link for example

```
<a href="http://google.com">google</a>
```

now i want to open this link when i load `Index.html`
i want to know how can i do this with `JQuery` or JavaScript ?

Comment: Is that a cross domain iframe? Can you edit this iframe source code?

Comment: No, i can not edit this i frame, just i have a script code that this code shows this i frame in my site, only i can see this iframe code from View Source menu of my browser

Comment: If it is a cross domain iframe then you are out of luck. You could still proxify it server side, but...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24688268/can-a-button-click-cause-an-event-in-iframe/

Comment: let me say that iframe has no ID or name, and every time i refresh my page the link address (href) inside the iframe changes

Comment: You mean i can not do that?it is a cross domain iframe, there is no way to get access to iframe elements?